# Find a finite sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the following sum :
$\frac{1}{1^2}+ \frac{1+2}{1^2 +2^2}+\frac{1+2+3}{1^2 +2^2 +3^2}+...+\frac{1+2+3+....n}{1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +....+n^2}$
I tried to unify the denominators but i got a complicated form so i could not go on ?

Comment: Well, since there are formulas for both numerator $1+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$ and denominator $1^2+\cdots +n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ then you can simplify this into $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k+1)/2}{k(k+1)(2k+1)/6}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3}{2k+1}$

Comment: @freakish After cancellation I would get harmonic series, any formula for finding their sum?

Comment: @AjayMishra I don't think there's a nice description for (this variant of) harmonic numbers, not sure though.

Comment: @AjayMishra Using the Polygamma Functions (to be precise it is enough to only invoke the Digamma Function) one could rewrite this one in a ["closed-form"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D1)%5En+3%2F(2k%2B1)); afterall it would just be the same series in disguise.

Comment: " I don't think there's a nice description for (this variant of) harmonic numbers, not sure though."  $\sum^n \frac 3{2k+1}= 3(\sum_{k=1;odd}^{2n+1} \frac 1k)=3[\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac 1k - \sum_{k=1; even}^{2n}\frac 1k]=3[H_{2n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{2k}= 3[H_{2n+1} - \frac 12H_n]$

Answer (score 4):

We obtain using the *[finite summation formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Powers_and_logarithm_of_arithmetic_progressions)*
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^nk&=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\\
  \end{align*}
and the *[harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)* $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1+2+\cdots+j}{1^2+2^2+\cdots+j^2}}
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\frac{1}{2}j(j+1)}{\frac{1}{6}j(j+1)(2j+1)}\\
> &=3\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{2j+1}\\
> &=3\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2j}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3\left(H_{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2}H_n\right)}
> \end{align*}